# Can I configure the DateTimeOffset object to be rendered in ISO 8061 for Azure Cosmos?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document structure I am saving to Azure Cosmos that looks like this:

```
public class CallIndex
{
    public string id;
    public DateTimeOffset callTime;
    public string source;
}
```

When I save a document, I use this command, and the data looks like this:

```
container.CreateItemAsync(obj, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
/* 
data:
{
    "callTime": "2020-09-30T20:17:28+00:00",
    "id": "352hyKL5agNtB4ic",
    "source": "five9"
}
*/
```

This works fine, but after some research, I realized we need to use the ISO 8061 DateTime standard (without the offset) in order to perform some server-side queries. Is there a way I can force the `CreateItemAsync` function to serialize the `DateTimeOffset` object in the standard ISO 8061 format? All my `callTime` objects are already converted to UTC before saving. We are using `DateTimeOffset` in order to make the conversion to client time zones simpler after we query data from the database. I would like my data to look like this after creating/replacing:

```
{
    "callTime": "2020-09-30T20:17:28.000000Z",
    "id": "352hyKL5agNtB4ic",
    "source": "five9"
}
```

Is that possible? Or am I better off changing my structure to use `DateTime` instead of `DateTimeOffset`?

Answer (score 1):

Since this reflects the default behavior of the JSON serializer, you'd need to override by providing the Cosmos client with your own [custom serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.serializer?view=azure-dotnet). Achieving the format would depend on the serializer.

What I've found is there is good reason **not** to fight this; use `DateTime` instead always with UTC values, and optionally along with the [IANA time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) name of the location that time applies to. This gives you guarantees about the serialization just working, Cosmos liking it, and being able to handle datetime arithmetic correctly within specific time zones both on server and client (NodaTime and date-fns libraries help here).

Also note that `DateTimeOffset` has a fundamental limitation around time zone ambiguity:

> Because a single DateTimeOffset value isn't tightly coupled with its
> time zone, it can't reflect a time zone's transition to and from
> daylight saving time. This can be problematic when date and time
> arithmetic is used to manipulate a DateTimeOffset value.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime)

In my mind, if you care about time zones in your app, it's better to steer clear of `DateTimeOffset`.